# Looking for JDOM2 XPath examples

Tags: java, xpath, jdom-2

I am using JDOM2 for the first time and I am looking for some XPATH based examples.

Ex: My XML looks as follows

```
<Root>
  <Parent id="1">
    <Child id="1" />
    <Child id="2" />
    <Child id="3" />
  </Parent>
  <Parent id="2">
    <Child id="1" />
    <Child id="2" />
    <Child id="3" />
  </Parent>
  <Parent id="3">
    <Child id="1" />
    <Child id="2" />
    <Child id="3" />
  </Parent>
</Root>
```

My background is .NET & XPATH traversing is very easier with System.XML

I am working on a (new to) Java application where I need to use XML. I am planning to use JDOM2. I want to use DOM parsing and not SAX.

I am looking for some examples on how to use XPATH with JDOM2.

Ex. How can I navigate to an element let's say `"/Root/Parent[@id='2']/Child[@id='3']"`

Can you guys give me some examples? I searched but I couldn't find one for JDOM2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, found this https://github.com/hunterhacker/jdom/wiki/JDOM2-A-Primer and seem to be helpful

Answer (score 2):

http://www.studytrails.com/java/xml/jdom2/java-xml-jdom2-xpath/

is an example of using JDOM2 and XPATH