# How to get an XML Tag belonging to another tag with specific attribute in Java?

Tags: java, xml, parsing

I want to get a tag from another tag specified with an attribute I have chosen. In this XML file for example, how do I proceed to print the mark 85 of the student 393?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<class>
<student rollno="393">
  <firstname>dinkar</firstname>
  <lastname>kad</lastname>
  <nickname>dinkar</nickname>
  <marks>85</marks>
</student>
<student rollno="493">
  <firstname>Vaneet</firstname>
  <lastname>Gupta</lastname>
  <nickname>vinni</nickname>
  <marks>95</marks>
</student>
<class>
```

I am writing in Java and using JDom as follows

```
 NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("student");
     for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {
        Node nNode = nList.item(temp);
        System.out.println("\nCurrent Element :" + nNode.getNodeName()); 
        Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
        System.out.println("Student roll no : " + eElement.getAttribute("rollno"));
        System.out.println("First Name : "+ eElement.getElementsByTagName("firstname").item(0).getTextContent());
        System.out.println("Last Name : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("lastname").item(0).getTextContent());
        System.out.println("Nick Name : "+ eElement.getElementsByTagName("nickname").item(0).getTextContent());
        System.out.println("Marks : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("marks").item(0).getTextContent()); 
     }
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following XPath expression to *find `student` element having `rollno` attribute equals `393` and then return the corresponding `marks` child element* :

```
//student[@rollno='393']/marks
```

I'm not familiar with JDom or Java in general, but JDom seems to support XPath :

1. [Looking for JDOM2 XPath examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15541652/looking-for-jdom2-xpath-examples)
2. [XPath with JDOM : JDOM « XML « Java](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/XML/XPathwithJDOM.htm)